# what is the location of custom commands

Tags: command

where can I find the description/details of the custom commands. In my linux server there is a custom command named `qsubm` that I need to check, but I don't know where it is written.

Comment: or `which qsubm` or `type qsubm` ?

Comment: @user4556274 unless you're using `tcsh` you may want to [be careful using `which`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using bash, the best way to find out is

```
type -a qsubm
```

Whether it's a shell function, an alias, or an executable, this will tell you.

Let's pretend for a moment that you get the answer "qsubm is /usr/bin/local/qsubm".  The next thing you should do is check what file type that is:

```
file /usr/bin/local/qsubm
```

If it's a binary executable, you're done.  You can't look at it directly and your best bet is to check around on your system or on the internet for related man pages or for source code.

However, if it is "POSIX shell script executable" or "Bourne shell script" or similar, you can inspect the text file directly with `less`:

```
less /usr/bin/local/qsubm
```

Use the space bar (or `f`) to go forward, and `b` to go back.  Press `q` to quit.

---

For alternatives to `type` and more history than you probably ever wanted to read, check out:

- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/135943)

Comment: To forestall inevitable corrections: Yes, I know you can inspect a binary executable directly.  But for most people (unless you know machine code), that won't be *useful.*  This is a beginner-level answer.

Comment: even if you do know machine code, modern C compiler optimizations make it pretty hard to do. Not to mention modern amd64 architecture CPUs have about four gazillion instructions.

Comment: What if it is a function? How to locate it then?

Comment: @Brambor you mean, how to locate the definition?  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322817/135943

Comment: @Wildcard I found it by brute force, but yes. This is exactly what I was looking for :D.

Answer (score 2):

You can always look for command thanks to "`whereis`" command and check it. If you find nothing, then this command is not a binary but rather alias. Try also write a
    `qsubm --help`
or 
    `man qsubm`

By the way is qsubm this http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Also **locate** is a great tool to find files. It's part of the mlocate package if you're on a linux flavor. You'll have to make sure your locate database is up to date. I use /usr/libexec/updatedb to do it but updatedb might just be in your path. Then just execute:

$ locate qsubm

Answer (score 1):

To amplify [Wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard)'s excellent answer, **command -v qsubm** is the POSIX-standard way to print the full pathname to an executable.  That works in almost all Bourne shells nowadays, including bash.  **command -V qsubm** produces a more verbose report if implemented, and will usually show alias definitions.

You want to use a shell built-in.  The shell you're using has its own logic for executing commands, and is the best reference for what it will do.  External commands such as **locate** and **whereis** do not have access to that logic, and can only make educated guesses based on common conventions.

Comment: locate indexes the entire filesystem and shows where the filename matches are without having to deal with $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by custom commands.

Sometimes I make custom commands by writing new `bash`/`sh` functions:

```
example ()
{
    enter custom code here
}
```

You can retrieve the code, after the fact, with `declare -f example`.

Hope that helps.