# How to find the file where a bash function is defined?

Tags: bash

I cannot figure out how to find the file where a bash function is defined (`__git_ps1` in my case).

I experimented with `declare`, `type`, `which`, but nothing tells me the source file.  I read somewhere that `declare` can print the file name and the line number, but it was not explained how.  The `help` page for `declare` does not say it either.

How can I get this information?

Comment: If the path to the function's file is not included in `$PATH`, then `type` won't work.  You might want to try just using `find` or `locate`.  `locate` will be much faster, since it uses a pre-existing database, but it won't work if the command was installed just recently.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322459/117549

Answer (score 46):

If you are prepared to run the function, then you can get the information by using `set -x` to trace the execution and setting the `PS4` variable.

1. Start bash with `--debugger` or else use `shopt -s extdebug` to record extra debugging info.
2. Set `PS4`, the 'prompt' printed when tracing to show the source line.
3. Turn on tracing.
4. you can then run your function and for each line you will get the filename of the function.
5. use `set +x` to turn off tracing.

So for this case you would run

```
bash --debugger
PS4='+ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} '
set -x ; __git_ps1 ; set +x
```

Comment: "-x      After expanding each simple command, for command, case command, select command, or arithmetic for command, display the expanded value of PS4, followed by  the  command  and its expanded arguments or associated word list." Nice!

Answer (score 42):

If you are not willing to run the function, you can still set up debugging and get the information. The steps are

1. start `bash --debugger` or `shopt -s extdebug` before the function is defined.
2. `declare -F __git_ps1`

and it will report where the function is defined.

The advantages of this method compared to seeing the annotated execution trace with PS4 are

- A lot less output
- It directly answers the question

The advantages of the execution trace are

- See all called functions at once
- See the relations between called functions
- See recursion

I *strongly* recommend having `shopt -s extdebug` at the start of both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` to cover the different [files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) used in different [Invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) cases.

Comment: It also works if `shopt -s extdebug` is called **after** the function is defined. Beware line numbers may be off (a current bug) if the function is declared through `eval`.

Comment: I was after a misguided completion for vpnc. After `bash --debugger` I had to actually trigger the completion to get the completion function defined and get it reported from `declare -F _vpnc`.

Comment: I do not have `~/.bash_profile` in Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Why do you _strongly_ recommend  having `shopt -s extdebug` set as default?

Comment: @jarno See the manual page, but it allows you to see this information, allows DEBUG traps to be inherited and has no downside as far as I can see. See the link for alternatives to ~/.bash_profile or just create it.

Comment: Thanks @icarus while I'm not sure I agree wih having the option enabled all the time -  this did help a lot, now part of my `~/.bashrc`: `wherefunc () { (shopt -s extdebug; declare -F "${*}"); }`

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't seem to be possible in `bash`, but it is in `zsh`:

```
$ type __git_ps1
> __git_ps1 is a shell function from /usr/share/git/git-prompt.sh
```

Comment: The question does specify bash...

Comment: @JeffSchaller: The obvious way to use this answer is to set up zsh to source the same files that bash would, then use it to find the definition.  This answer isn't suggesting switching to zsh, just that it's obviously a useful tool that understands shell syntax better than generic tools like `find` / `locate` / `grep`.

Comment: I would claim, then, @PeterCordes , that this answer currently does not do what you say it should do in order to answer the Question. I don't know if zsh natively reads the same files that bash does.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Agreed this answer is in need of improvement.  zsh almost certainly doesn't read the same `~/.whatever` files as bash by default, and will only give useful answers for functions defined in shared locations like in this case, that aren't redefined in `~/.bashrc` or whatever.

Comment: Based on @icarus's answer `wherefunc () { (shopt -s extdebug; declare -F "${*}"); }`
meaning it is quite possible in bash (not sure about circa 2016)

Answer (score 9):

[@icarus's great solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322824/3645) works for **functions,** as long as they are defined literally and not the result of an `eval` of the contents of another file (in which the file with the `eval` will show up as the source). It will not print the source file of aliases, shell built-ins (like `echo`) and executables (binary or not), and I believe this information is not available in general. Some commands might print their source files (and may even be truthful about it), either in the course of normal execution or in response to a signal.

`__git_ps1` is defined in `/usr/share/git/git-prompt.sh` and `/usr/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh` on my system, Arch Linux, so it may be the same for you.

Have a look at the *Invocation* section of `man bash` if you want look for commands specifically sourced at the start of the shell - they may source other files which in turn source other files.

Comment: Can one get a list of files that are sourced upon starting `bash`?

Comment: @pfnuesel - it's up to you. The defaults are in `$HOME/.bashrc` and in `$HOME/.profile`. See: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html which explains some of the details of when and how each file is sourced.

Comment: @Joe https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html is a much better reference. `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, `$HOME/.bash_login`, and the contents of `$ENV` and `$BASH_ENV` need to be added to your list.

Comment: @icarus - Thanks. That is a better explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Declare a function with the same name and set it readonly as early as possible, then activate xtrace mode, something like:

```
__git_ps1(){ :;}
readonly -f __git_ps1
set -x
```

After that when you log in you will see trace information that includes sourcing of files. In the moment there is an attempt for a declaration of the existing readonly function, you will see an error message. The last sourced file before it should contain the declaration you look for.

You may need to put this in the system bash profile. Also remember to revert the changes after finding the culprit.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try this?

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

or any of the other commands found here:

[How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-to-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

It seems that I need to give you more of an explanation. Your question asks ""
Thus if you run the following command, it should return all files where a bash function is defined.

```
grep -rnw 'Path2Search' -e "#!/bin/bash"
```

[BASH Programming - Functions | Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html)

Comment: Link only answers are absolutely not encouraged. Please add some explanation.