# How to know where shell variables and functions are set?

Tags: bash, shell, variable, function

When I type the `set` command in my system I've got this extract out :

```
__colormgr_commandlist='
    create-device
    create-profile
    delete-device
    delete-profile
    device-add-profile
    device-get-default-profile
    device-get-profile-for-qualifier
    device-inhibit
    device-make-profile-default
    device-set-kind
    device-set-model
    device-set-serial
    device-set-vendor
    find-device
    find-device-by-property
    find-profile
    find-profile-by-filename
    get-devices
    get-devices-by-kind
    get-profiles
    get-sensor-reading
    get-sensors
    get-standard-space
    profile-set-filename
    profile-set-qualifier
    sensor-lock
    sensor-set-options
    '
__grub_script_check_program=grub-script-check
_backup_glob='@(#*#|*@(~|.@(bak|orig|rej|swp|dpkg*|rpm@(orig|new|save))))'
_xspecs=([freeamp]="!*.@(mp3|ogg|pls|m3u)" [cdiff]="!*.@(dif?(f)|?(d)patch)?(.@([gx]z|bz2|lzma))" [bibtex]="!*.aux" [rgview]="*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)" [oowriter]="!*.@(sxw|stw|sxg|sgl|doc?([mx])|dot?([mx])|rtf|txt|htm|html|?(f)odt|ott|odm)" [chromium-browser]="!*.@(?([xX]|[sS])[hH][tT][mM]?([lL]))" [tex]="!*.@(?(la)tex|texi|dtx|ins|ltx|dbj)" [netscape]="!*.@(?([xX]|[sS])[hH][tT][mM]?([lL]))"
.../..
_xinetd_services () 
{ 
    local xinetddir=/etc/xinetd.d;
    if [[ -d $xinetddir ]]; then
        local restore_nullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob);
        shopt -s nullglob;
        local -a svcs=($( printf '%s\n' $xinetddir/!($_backup_glob) ));
        $restore_nullglob;
        COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W '${svcs[@]#$xinetddir/}' -- "$cur" ));
    fi
}
dequote () 
{ 
    eval printf %s "$1" 2> /dev/null
}
quote () 
{ 
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
quote_readline () 
{ 
    local quoted;
    _quote_readline_by_ref "$1" ret;
    printf %s "$ret"
}
```

I checked all files in my knowledge as `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, and/or `~/.bashrc`. I didn't find any generation  script or code calling.

Do you have any advice where is come from ?

Comment: Did you also check the files sourced from those files (if any)?

Comment: Directories with additional files, most importantly `/etc/profile.d` have been common for about a decade. You have to read the files and see which other files they may include.

Comment: maybe files in `/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: Similar to [How to determine where an environment variable came from](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/813)

Comment: Ah, here's the other part too: [How to find the file where a bash function is defined?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322817/170373)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas similar? maybe even a duplicate?

Comment: @Bananguin No, because dubis is actually looking for the definition of shell variables and functions, not the definition of environment variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the functions, Bash can tell you where they came from:

```
$ help declare
...
  -F        restrict display to function names only (plus line 
            number and source file when debugging) 

$ shopt -s extdebug
$ declare -F quote_readline
quote_readline 150 /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

(I found this mentioned in an [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21132246/6372809).)

For the environment variables, there are a bunch of good ways to find them here: [How to determine where an environment variable came from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/170373)

Most of those functions seem related to command line completion, my Ubuntu system has them in `/usr/share/bash-completion/` as shown above.

FWIW, `__colormgr_commandlist` seems related to completion too, there's a script containing it [here](https://github.com/hughsie/colord/blob/master/data/colormgr).