# What and usage of shell function? As listed using declare -F

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to jump start my Linux (Centos) knowledge and trying to understand what is "default" Shell Functions listed by `declare -F`. No idea what these functions is called, I just label them as "default".
I googled it, but what I got is about scripting. Is there article which explain what are they for, where (defined in which file), purpose and usage. Or someone can give a short write-up? 
From the look of it, they look like utilities.

For example; `declare -f _have`

```
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin type $1 &>/dev/null
```

What is the `type $1` do?

BTW, I created one from the shell prompt `function App1 ()`, then `{ ls }`, when I check using `declare -f App1` found **ls** had became `ls --color=auto`.

Answer (score 2):

`type` is a builtin command to bash, so is described in the manual. Your `_have` function searches your path and 3 extra directories to see if you have a program (or alias or function), and returns a true or false value.

Your "default" functions are declared in files read by the files read at startup. You might find [How to find the file where a bash function is defined?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322817/how-to-find-the-file-where-a-bash-function-is-defined) helpful. They exist because someone who put Centos together thought them to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank icarus. I found `type` is a command, but as there is no `;` as a separator, I think it is something else. Just tested `VAR=Apple ls` and `VAR=Apple ; ls` , the result is the same, now I know `;` is not required. But now I wonder is there a difference.

Found where is start from; `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`, then  `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.
googled and found this *https://github.com/scop/bash-completion*
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of thanking icarus by posting a new answer; upvote and/or accept their answer. Note that `VAR=Apple ls` only sets VAR for the duration of `ls`; it's gone afterwards. Using `VAR=Apple; ls` sets VAR in the current shell (but doesn't export it).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I can't upvote. I will check can I accept as answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I can't upvote (no reputation).   BTW, I tried this `VAR5=GG echo ${VAR5}test` and the output is `test`, then I tried `VAR5=GG ; echo ${VAR5}test` and the output is as expected `GGtest`. Still trying to figure out, shouldn't the first one also returned `GGtest`?. As far as I know bash_completion.sh provide a set of utilities, but I still wonder is it important/commonly used? Will disabling it break things? It look dated in the distro, so it kind of make me curious. Anyway, I need to get my fundamental knowledge up first.