# Scope and origin of some common variables in Bash completion functions

Tags: bash

There are variables like cur, prev, split, words and cword. They seem to have value I can use in my completion functions. Where are they defined and assigned? Are they exported somewhere? Should I declare those variables as local with same name in my completions?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the pre-defined function `_init_completion` (whose declaration can be found like [this](https://superuser.com/a/229038/490855)) in my completion function, you should declare certain variables as local.

Quote from above of the declaration of `_init_completion`:

```
# Initialize completion and deal with various general things: do file
# and variable completion where appropriate, and adjust prev, words,
# and cword as if no redirections exist so that completions do not
# need to deal with them.  Before calling this function, make sure
# cur, prev, words, and cword are local, ditto split if you use -s.
```

Maybe it is best to declare `words` as local array because it is used as an array. If you use other such functions you may have to declare some other variables; it is better to check the code for what is needed, I think.

Test for variable scope in Bash:

If I use `local` in function `a`

```
(
    x=1
    (
        unset -v x
        b() { echo $x; x=b; }
        a() { local x=a; b; echo $x; }
        a
        if [[ ${x+x} ]]; then
            echo $x
        else
            echo 'x is unset'
        fi
    )
    echo $x
)
```

output is

```
a
b
x is unset
1
```

but if I do not use `local` in function `a`

```
(
    x=1
    (
        unset -v x
        b() { echo $x; x=b; }
        a() { x=a; b; echo $x; }
        a
        if [[ ${x+x} ]]; then
            echo $x
        else
            echo 'x is unset'
        fi
    )
    echo $x
)
```

output is

```
a
b
b
1
```

i.e. the value is available for the caller of `a`.

Comment: Similar to the linked SU Q/A, on U&L we have https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322817/315749