# Ubuntu 20.04 Shell - pressing TAB shows weird 'autocomplete output'

Tags: ubuntu, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have a strange issue, and really not sure how to search for a similar question on StackExchange.

This is related to `Ubuntu 20.04 command-line`.

When I press `TAB` key, which 'autocompletes' appends really weird results as part of the 'input for my current command'.

For instance:

```
Typing: (cd and pressing TAB afterwards)
....
cd words=("${@:3:2}")
cword="$3"
cur="$3"
cur="$3"
cword="$3"
prev="$3"
words=("${@:3:2}")
stage^C
```

Same when typing `bash + TAB`

```
bash words=("${@:3:2}")
cword="$3"
cur="$3"
cur="$3"
cword="$3"
prev="$3"
words=("${@:3:2}")
^C
```

Shell autocomplete is behaving strangely recently, not sure how to fix this. (Also apologies again, I really do not know how to phrase this correctly or even find a similar question).

#### NOTE:

`reset` only clears the console, but the issue still remains afterwards!

Comment: That looks like the sort of thing you'd get from a misplaced quotation mark or something.
Check your ~/.bashrc to see if the text you see (`words=...`) appear there. Maybe you have syntax error somewhere around there.

Comment: Thanks for hint, unfortunately that's not it.. I verified the ./bashrc file, it remained unchanged since April 5, which was when the server was setup.  I know for sure I didn't edit something myself.

Comment: I had the exact same problem but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/670171/1292456) resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your shell is Bash. I can replicate your problem by redefining `eval` like this:

```
eval() { echo "$1"; }
```

or similarly. Completion functions use `eval`. They expect `eval` to be `eval` *the* shell builtin. If `eval` is tampered with then they may misbehave.

My tests indicate that `eval` being an alias or an executable does not break completions, so it's most likely a function in your case.

Invoke

```
type eval
```

Normally the output should be `eval is a shell builtin`. If you get `eval is a function` then invoke

```
unset -f eval
```

and check if completions behave better (or at least differently).

You should investigate where the function comes from. A manual method is to check the startup files (`~/.bashrc` [and such](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)) and everything they source. There are better methods. Proceed like this:

```
shopt -s extdebug   # enable extra debugging info
declare -F eval
```

This will tell you the line number and the source file. (Finally run `shopt -u extdebug` to disable debugging.)

The above method should be enough to locate the definition of the function. Just in case, few other methods are here: [*How to find the file where a bash function is defined*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322817/108618).

After you find the definition of this `eval` function, get rid of it and let `eval` be the builtin. Notes:

- Deleting the definition will not automatically fix already running shells. Spawn a new shell; log out and log in; when in doubt, reboot.
- Deleting the definition will break anything that actually needs the function, so further investigation may be required: for what reason was the function there? Consider renaming instead of deleting (at least initially, temporarily), in case the code in the definition is not expendable.
- The function may be defined more than once (and the most recently sourced definition wins). If deleting the definition does not bring the builtin back, there's probably a definition left. Repeat the method.

If completions are not fully fixed, examine the output of `declare -F` and check for other functions that replace builtins (use [`compgen -b`](https://askubuntu.com/a/512952/693277) to know what to search for). If needed, analyze them like you just did with `eval` and fix similarly.

Comment: Thank you, what a technical answer!  For some reason, my shell is now fine again this morning  (`eval is a shell builtin`).  I will definitely look at this when I experience the issue again!  Thanks so much for the in-depth explanation on how to debug.

Comment: I think it might be a tool (docker/dbdeployer) that also uses autocomplete features, one of those two might be doing something, and unexpected on the shell used.  I will give more information if I find anything.